# How should dispatches on two types be done?

Tags: enums, rust

In this code:

```
impl Msg {
    fn apply_to(&self, state: &mut State) {
        match (self, state) {
            (Msg::MsgA(m), State::StateOne(s)) => {
                m.apply_to_state_one(s);
            },

            (Msg::MsgB(m), State::StateOne(s)) => {
                m.apply_to_state_one(s);
            },

            // FIXME: can these two dispatches be made into one
            (Msg::MsgC(m), State::StateOne(s)) => {
                m.apply_to_common_state(&mut s.common);
            },
            (Msg::MsgC(m), State::StateTwo(s)) => {
                m.apply_to_common_state(&mut s.common);
            },
        
            (Msg::MsgD(m), State::StateTwo(s)) => {
                m.apply_to_state_two(s);
            },
        
            (_, _) => { // don't care
                ()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

there is unappealing boilerplate, more in the full playground.

In full: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=acca055b435ae21d141eaac70e097e72

I want each `Msg` to be able to be applied to a `StateOne`, a `StateTwo` or either (by way of their common field, `common`).

`Msg`s should error when applied to a state for which they don't have an implementation.

I would prefer that all the logic was in the individual messages, with none in `Msg` or the `State`s.

How can I best express this in Rust's type system?

---

Update: I'm particularly keen to know if my general approach to this problem is correct for Rust, or whether there are better solutions if either the messages or states were generics or `dyn trait` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using struct destructuring in order to combine them:

```rust
(Msg::MsgC(m), State::StateOne(StateOne {mut common, ..}))
| (Msg::MsgC(m), State::StateTwo(StateTwo {mut common, ..})) => {
    m.apply_to_common_state(&mut common);
},
```

It isn't the prettiest, but after [or patterns](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54883) get stabilized it might be able to be reduced into `(Msg::MsgC(m), State::StateOne(StateOne {mut common, ..}) | State::StateTwo(StateTwo {mut common, ..}))`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Those solutions, while useful improvements, still don't give me the feeling that I'm doing this right.   (I'll write a Java solution, as a comparison.)